# How to select right text with RichTextBox.Select in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a RichText in my RichTextBox.
If i print textBox.Text.Length it is shorter than if I print textBox.TextLength.
I want to index search inside the textBox and find a certain string to select, but since they missmatch in length, if i use a textBox.Text.IndexOf("bla"), i get wrong position.

How do I do to get the right position to select?

Comment: Post code and data that reproduces that.  I get Text.Length = TextLength every time.

Comment: Will that: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-richtextbox-find(system-string) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RichTextBox1.Select();
RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("bla"), "bla".Length);
```